# Call ASP Web API Cross Domain using jQuery Ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an ASP Web API application that works fine using a web browser cross domain. It returns all expected data in JSON which I can clearly see in Firefox and in Fiddler. For example, using Firefox:

```
http://mywebapidomain.com/api/drink/
```

returns:

```
<ArrayOfDrink>
    <Drink>
        <AlcoholContent>0.05</AlcoholContent>
        <Id>1</Id>
        <Name>12 oz beer</Name>
        <OuncesPerDrink>12</OuncesPerDrink>
    </Drink>
    <Drink>
        <AlcoholContent>0.12</AlcoholContent>
        <Id>2</Id>
        <Name>Glass wine</Name>
        <OuncesPerDrink>5</OuncesPerDrink>
    </Drink>
</ArrayOfDrink>
```

I can see similar success using Fiddler. Up until now I have had a page that resided on the Web API domain and used jQuery to make the call, like this:

```
// AJAX Call - Get Drink Types
function getDrinkTypes() {

    return $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "http://mywebapidomain.com/api/drink/",
        dataType: "json",

        success: function (data) {
            DrinkTypeList = data;
        },

        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert(xhr.statusText + " - " + xhr.status + "\n\n" + xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

Again, this worked fine and returned all expected data.

Without getting into a whole other issue here, I had a sound reason to place the above jQuery code in a script on an entirely different server/domain. Now the Ajax call fails. Upon inspecting `xhr`, `status` and `error`, I am seeing the following:

```
xhr.readyState = 4
xhr.status = 404
xhr.statusMessage = "undefined"

status = "error"

error = ""
```

Viewing with Fiddler, I see the raw request:

```
OPTIONS http://mywebapidomain.com/api/drink/ HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Origin: http://localhost:65103
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type, accept
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0; Touch)
Host: mywebapidomain.com
Content-Length: 0
DNT: 1
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
```

The response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 23 Jan 2014 08:48:57 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

I do not have CORS or JSONP support configured on the ASP/MVC4 Web API domain.

Earlier on in this project I ran into this issue and did some research. I read that jQuery Ajax makes an initial call that web browsers do not. I have totally forgotten what this is called, but it is evident by the `OPTIONS` in the above raw request header from Fiddler. Since I didn't understand it, I opted to run the client jQuery on the same domain and include it in an `iframe` on the alternate domain. This had its own complications, and so I am back t squaring off with this issue.

There are a lot of articles related to this problem, but I have been unable to make sense of them. I just don't know how to handle this. :S

As I have been typing this question I am seeing many similar questions that have already been asked. I've opened them in a separate window and read through each one, but none of them seem to be helping me understand what I have to do...

Can someone point me specifically on how to resolve this cross domain jQuery Ajax issue?

Answer (score 3):

i think you must enable cross site forgery request , you have many options to do this like
add approprite header to your response 
take a look at these links
<[adding header to response](http://markchouanard.com/post/35052747409/executing-cross-domain-post-using-jquery-and-asp-net)>

<[using attributes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/02/20/implementing-cors-support-in-asp-net-web-apis.aspx)>

Comment: If my jQuery Ajax calls make only GET requests to the Web API, is this the easiest way? I do not need to make any POST/PUT requests. This all seems to be required for jQuery Ajax since the Web API is working perfect from IE, Firefox, etc. It is the jQuery preflight request that is requiring the consideration. I am just wondering if there is anything I can do to ONLY the jQuery without having to modify the ASP Web API code.

Comment: the cross site origin allow is related to asp.net , infact when your code receive a request that it is not related to your site throws an exception , becuase of these i think that you must change your asp.net code